# MAUP: correlation increases with aggregation, would error decrease?

Tags: spatial, aggregation

I know that, due to MAUP, as you coarsen the scale of analysis, you can expect the correlation coefficient to increase, variance to decrease (?), and regression coefficients to fluctuate.  Is there any predictable effect on the errors from a regression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Modifiable Areal Unit Problem (MAUP) is a particular case of *aggregation bias*, and the seminal papers on the MAUP build off of early investigations into such bias. Your question has, to my mind, a few misconceptions in it. First, it is *not* the case that correlation necessarily increases with aggregation; correlation can go either way. For example, I have seen real data where depressive symptoms are associated with BMI in roughly a 'U' shape. However, if one examines the association with the aggregated categories 'underweight', 'normal weight', or 'overweight' the association diminishes to almost nil, since the sloped part of the non-aggregated relationships do not correspond to the numerical cut-offs for the definitions of 'overweight' and 'underweight'.

Second, your question leaves out a critically important issue: it is not merely *scale* that affects correlations, autocorrelations, variance measures, and inferences, but *categorization*. That is for a given scale (i.e. a given number of units to be aggregated to) the function that determines *which individual* (or lower level unit) ends up in *which higher level unit* also affects all these statistical measures.

The critical insight to take away from the MAUP literature is not the idea that there is a bias to be corrected, but rather that **aggregation requires substantive theoretical justification.** For example, if interested in school-children's vehicular-pedestrian collisions, *school districts* (which implement crossing-guard policies) would be a more appropriate definition of neighborhood than, say, *police precincts*.

**Example of categorization**

In the picture below, the circle represents a city, and the blue dots represent affluent individuals, while the yellow triangles represent impoverished individuals (the thick black horizontal line might represent the *tracks* for which there is a "wrong side of" :). The red lines divide the city into three neighborhoods; notice that there is an economic gradient with the wealthier neighborhood up north, the middling neighborhood in the center, and the impoverished neighborhood in the south.

[image]

Now notice in this second image, that the city is identical with respect to the residents and their individual distributions of affluence/impoverishment, except that the red lines have been rearranged so that no there is **no economic gradient**, in other words the between neighborhood variance is now zero (also, for some reason the tracks are a different color, but that's irrelevant :). The *scale* (3 neighborhoods) remains the same, but the *categorization function* (who ends up in which neighborhood) is different.

[image]

**References**
Dudley, G. (1991). Scale, aggregation, and the modifiable areal unit problem. *The Operational Geographer*, 9(3):28–33.

Gehlke, C. E. and Biehl, K. (1934). Certain Effects of Grouping Upon the Size of the Correlation Coefficient in Census Tract Material. *Journal of the American Statistical Association*, 29(185):169–170. **[One of the first ever papers to address aggregation bias.]**

Lee, H. T. K. and Kemp, Z. (2000). Hierarchical reasoning and on-line analytical processing of spatial and temporal data. In *Proceedings of the 9th International Symposium on Spatial Data Handling*, Beijing, P.R. China. International Geographic Union. **[This is one of the best papers I have read on the subject, but I think you have to track one of the authors down to obtain a copy.]**

Openshaw, S. (1983). *The modifiable areal unit problem. Concepts and Techniques in Modern Geography*. Geo Books, Norwich, UK.

Openshaw, S. and Taylor, P. J. (1979). A million or so correlation coefficients: Three experiments on the modifiable area unit problem. In Wrigley, N. (ed.) *Statistical Applications in the Spatial Sciences*, pages 127–144. Pion, London, UK.

Comment: Excellent post. I've edited the last reference slightly.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and especially the references. In my case, though, -- and it is my fault for not specifying -- I am considering raster grid support for a (formerly) point data set, so "scale" is the lens through which I see the problem (Marceau 1999).  I plan to run a regression at several pixel sizes to see what's going on, but I wondered if anyone knew how MAUP might affect errors (e.g., heteroskedasticity or smaller RMSE).  Results in my field keep reporting lower errors at coarser scales, and I am suspicious . . .

Comment: @JKelly As long as you are comfortable with whatever relationship you find being possibly entirely an artifact of your aggregation process... :) Let me put it to you this way: you know the ecological fallacy? Population-level relationships do not necessarily hold at the individual level (and, indeed, the *opposite* relationships may hold), and the atomistic fallacy is vice versa (individual relationships don't tell one about population-level relationships). What you propose seems dead set on fallacious inference.

Comment: This is just lidar height measurements.  Not that different from making a DEM from survey points, but (I'm still figuring out) perhaps unwise to admit into regression analysis with other data as is being done routinely by smarter folks than me. I _do_ recognize those fallacies, but trees to plots is a very common aggregation (by sum, not mean).  My worry is that height points to mean-height cells is less well-founded.

Comment: @JKelly Well I am out of my zone now: no experience with LIDAR and ways of aggregating it. Perhaps there are theoretical justifications for what you propose...

Comment: I don't think the different application to LIDAR changes the principles. Aggregation means losing information on within-area variability, but otherwise its effects depend on how much loss and on everything else.

Comment: @NickCox It also implies *bias*.

Comment: @Alexis Always and with respect to what? I'm agnostic that you can even write down a correct scale-free relationship with respect to which others are biased here, but I am happy to be overwhelmed with logic and/or references.

Comment: @NickCox Sorry. Bias in correlation—or fallacy if you prefer, in interpreting correlation. Given latitude in scale and categorization functions arbitrary correlations may be obtained. Robinson's example in the seminal paper on the ecological fallacy gives the illustration of a small and positive correlation between an individual being immigrant and being illiterate in 1930 Census data, but a moderate and negative correlation between state prevalence of immigrants and state prevalence of illiteracy. So area aggregates are biased estimates of within-area correlations.

Comment: I see what you mean, but that is a human science-biased picture in which data for individual people define "true" relationships. OK, but that won't work for e.g. mosses, corals, soil pH, temperature or any other variable for which individuals are undefinable and for which scale is at choice subject to limitations of measurement procedure.

Comment: @NickCox Since **aggregation requires substantive theoretical justification** the conclusions that can be drawn from arbitrary aggregation functions (scale and classification) are of what value? (Other than of cargo cult rituals designed to make the researchers look "scientific?")

Comment: Good question. Some large fraction of the Earth, ecological and environmental sciences cycles around it directly or indirectly.